# $$typeof is an invalid action type when setting up ActionTypes in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So, I'm setting up Redux in a new React application and I'm running into this issue. I'm not using Typescript and am just trying to setup one Type right now.

```js
import createTypes from "redux-create-action-types";

const Types = createTypes(
  "THIS_IS_A_VALID_TYPE"
);

export default Types;
```

This is what my actionTypes file looks like. This should be a completely valid type, though I get back

```
$$typeof is an invalid action type
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not saying that this is the issue, but `redux-create-action-types` has very few users and hasn't been updated in five years. You may want to consider another solution.

Comment: Yep. You really shouldn't be using that. Instead, you should be using our official Redux Toolkit package, and following our guidelines for app setup.  See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start .